# How to get two audio outputs to 1 speaker?

Tags: laptop, audio, splitters, video-game-console

I have a laptop and an xbox/nintendo switch. All of them are connected to a HDMI splitter with audio extractor. The audio extractor is hooked up to speakers. The audio works on the speakers for the gaming consoles, but not detected at all from the laptop. For the laptop, the audio comes from the laptop still. I am trying to get the laptop audio to come from the speakers too.

Now I'm considering getting some sort of spliter where I can connect the laptop audio out to, and the HDMI splitter to, and the output will be connected to the speakers. Is there such a device/cable for this? Some sort of spliter/switch for audio.

If looking on amazon, I would need amazon.ca.

Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure the laptop set to output to external speakers?

Answer (score 1):

HDMI carries audio, so your laptop should be able to output the audio the same way your Xbox and Nintendo Switch are able to. Be sure to select the audio extractor as your sound output on your laptop.

Now if you decide that you STILL want an audio switcher, this [Nobsound Little Bear](https://www.amazon.ca/Nobsound-Audio-Switcher-Selector-Splitter/dp/B0787X4J4V/) is pretty popular.